# pandoc LaTex add CSS to create PDF

Tags: latex, pdf-generation, markdown, pandoc

I have the a markdown file and a css file in the same folder at same level.

I want to use the css in creaing the PDF output.

I tired the following command

`pandoc -c pandoc.css  input.md -o output.pdf`

The styles did not apply.

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 5):

By default, pandoc uses LaTeX under the hood to generate the PDF, which doesn't understand CSS.

However, if installed, pandoc can also use `wkhtmltopdf` which does undertand CSS. To generate a PDF with wkhtmltopdf, include `-t html5`, e.g. `pandoc -t html5 input.md -o output.pdf`.

To include an external CSS file, either use `--css mystyles.css` or use markdown document metadata like:

```
---
css: mystyles.css
---

my document body
```

Comment: on a side note is there a simpler way to create pdf files with code block...pandoc has it's own learning curve

Comment: don't understand your comment... :)

Comment: I want to create pdf file which has syntax hilighting and code blocks..using pandoc is not the best option so far for me as there is a lot of configutation that is taking focus out of my content..Is there a simpler tool that I can use to create pdf with code that has syntax hilighting

Comment: pandoc should have syntax highlighting in code blocks in both wkhtmltopdf and latex-based PDF generation... you'll have to post a more specific question if something's not working for you...